# Having issues with forking a process

Tags: c++, unix, process, fork

So I'm writing a UNIX shell for a class of mine and basically I take in an argument, if the argument has '&' at the end of it then I need the parent process to invoke wait();.

My problem here is that the program should accept inputs until I type exit, so everything is in a 'while' loop. Things run perfect until I call a command with '&' at the end of it, and then I can see that the parent process ends, then the child ends, but then I'm not at my normal prompt to accept an input which is "osh> ".

So basically here's my normal output when I run a simple command:

```
osh> ls -l
child:0
a.out  main  main.cpp  main.cpp~
parent: 8695
```

But then when I run a command with the '&' at the end this happens:

```
osh> ls -l &
parent: 27082
osh> child:0
total 44
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser users 10368 Mar  1 14:46 a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser users 23368 Mar  1 14:00 main
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser users  1658 Mar  1 14:46 main.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser users  1676 Mar  1 14:45 main.cpp~
<cursor is here accepting commands, but no osh> prompt>
```

If anyone has any comments or suggestions, would be appreciated. I feel like it's just a small bug but I've ran through a debugger multiple times and can't find anything. I just don't have that much experience forking things. Here's the full code to look at:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 //the maximum length command

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char* args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; //command line arguments
  char str[41]; //intitialize string for input
  int should_run = 1; //flag to determine when to exit program
  bool status; //status of whether or not an ampersand is in the passed argument

  while (should_run) {
    int index = 0;

    cout << "osh> ";
    fflush(stdout);

    cin.getline(str, 41);

    args[index] = strtok(str, " ");

    while (args[index] != NULL) {
      index++;
      args[index] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    if (strcmp (args[0], "exit") == 0) //in input is "exit", exit the while loop
      break;

    if (*args[index - 1] == '&') //check whether to run processes concurrently
      status = true;

    args[index - 1] = NULL; //remove & to make sure arguments are valid

    // (1) fork a child process using fork()
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { //error handling
      perror("Fork Failed.");
      break;
      }
    // (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
    if (pid == 0) {
      //child process
      cout << "child:" << pid << endl;
      if ( execvp (args[0], args) == -1 ) {
        perror ("exec");
      }
    }

    // (3) if command didn't included &, parent will invoke wait()
    //parent process
    if (pid > 0) {
        // parent process
       if (!status) {
         wait(0);
         }
       cout << "parent: " << pid << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit: Also just realized that on my second output I posted, it shows "osh>" a second time after the parent process, not sure how to describe that error.

Comment: That's pretty much how it works in every other Unix shell.

Comment: Any reason for not writing this in C, which it almost all is?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Just more comfortable with C++

Comment: @immibis just worried about my prompt not showing up really. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: @HOAX That's not obvious from your code.

Comment: @HOAX The prompt does show up, it shows up on the third line of your output.

Comment: This is not an error, since `&` is a request for concurrency, then you faced it! Child and parent are concurrent. I'm not sure why you would consider this as an error as any shell will behave exactly the same and it is inherent to concurrency.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are already at the command prompt:

```
osh> child:0
total 44
```

That's your command, prompt, the `osh>` prompt.

Your issue here is that your computer is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, and not what you wanted it to do. Your code (which has an unrelated, major bug, which I'll get to in the moment) says not to wait until the child process finishes, and proceed, if `&` was entered.

And that's exactly what happened. The child process got started, and your parent process immediately emitted the next `osh>` prompt. And, it did it so fast, before the child process even got a change to produce any output. As such, the output from the child process appears on your terminal, after the `osh>` prompt. Since your parent process already produced its prompt, it is now waiting for your next input, and it has no reason not to continue to wait, after the child process has terminated, and finished producing its output.

That answers the question of what happened to your prompt. You did not explain what you expected to happen, so nothing further can be said about it; but if you want to reissue the prompt again, after the child process terminates, you can do that by properly handling the `SIGCHLD` signal. See your C++ book for more information.

As far as your unrelated bug, it's actually two bugs:

```
if (*args[index - 1] == '&')
  status = true;

args[index - 1] = NULL; //re
```

First bug: anything that starts with `'&'`, and not just "&" by itself, will trigger the background job behavior.

Second bug: if `'&'` was not entered, this code will still chop off the last word that was entered. Which is why when you entered the command `ls -l`, you ended up executing `ls`, and getting the resulting output, from your first command.

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy response, will look into my errors.

Comment: Note than in the POSIX shell (Bash, Korn, …), an `&` marks the end of a command unless it is followed by another `&&` (well, that still marks the end of the command — it's a different terminator, though) — or unless it's one of the obscure [Bash redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) syntaxes that uses `&` as the first character (`&>` and relatives).

Comment: Hey Sam, would I be able to use waitpid instead of handling the SIGCHLD directly? Having a hard time understanding this concept

Comment: `waitpid()` blocks until the process terminates. Your program will be unable to do anything else until the child process terminates. You could use `WNOHANG`, but you still have to know when the child process terminates. You are approaching this issue from a completely wrong perspective. You need to figure out, first, what your program should be doing and then figure out the right system calls and how to use them, not the other way around.